# Is there a way to convince Doxygen to parse documentation blocks in an array initialization

Tags: arrays, c, doxygen

I would like to document the elements of an array like the following:

```
typedef struct Tokens
{
  const char *name;
  int value;
} Tokens;

/** @addtogroup token_reference
    @{
*/

/** @brief The set of tokens */
static Tokens tokens[] = {
  /** @par Token A 
      Stuff about A
   */
  { "A", 1 },
  /** @par Token B 
      Stuff about B
   */
  { "B", 2 }
}

/** @} */
```

My Doxyfile has `EXTRACT_STATIC=YES` set, and I can see the `The set of tokens` documentation in the output, but none of the `@par`s in the initializer code.

Is there any way to convince Doxygen to look inside the initializer code for comments? The motivation here is to keep the documentation up to date when new tokens are added to the list by documenting the entries themselves, rather than keeping a separate documentation set elsewhere.

**Doxygen Version:** 1.9.3

Comment: Do you mean to have something analogous to what is happening with an `enum` where it is possible to document the individual values? To the best om my knowledge doxygen does not provide such a possibility for initializers.

Comment: Yes, the `enum` capability is more or less analogous to what I'm looking for. I figured there was no equivalent for array initializers, but was hoping there was something I had missed -- Thanks